# Bootstrap Modal Using Multiple Hyperlinks on a Page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have used bootstrap Modal for opening the popup modal in order to set the authorities of my accounts. when i click on first link, it opens accurately. But when i click on any other link. previous data is displayed again. i have tried it multiple times but still unsuccessful.
[image: Here is The Preview of My Page]

Here is the Code for Table that loads the whole list:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
    <tr>
    <th>Code</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Authorities</th>
    <th>Password</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
<?php
foreach($res as $data) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $data[INST_CODE]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data[INST_NAME]; ?><?php echo "  ($insttype)"; ?></td>

        <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-info" href="auth2.php?inst_code=<?php echo $data[INST_CODE]; ?> ">Authorities</a></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

Here is Modal Code:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

auth2.php contains the contents to display. Please Guide Me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put following script in page where Modal call button is located

```
<script>
//jQuery Library Comes First
//Bootstrap Library
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
          $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    });
});
</script>
```

It will remove the previous data when closed and load new data when modal open on click to next row modal button.

Answer (score 0):

create your modal code in for loop and provide each element a dynamic id
`<td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" class="btn btn-info" >Authorities</a></td>`
`<td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" class="btn btn-info" >Authorities</a></td>`
.
.
.
etc

and modal code will have different id and each will be in for loop

Comment: then try to remove the href and keep only data-target

Comment: @Nikita this is not possible, in loop, he can't create `data-target="#myModal1"` and `data-target="#myModal2"` onwards, only way is if OP add the counter to `data-target` and next thing OP has to do is create modals `<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">` respectively and suppose he has 100 records so hope you don't want him to create 100 `<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">` modals